# Cut a letter from each line of a file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I try to eliminate from a file_in.dat as follow:

```
283  K00845.01  16.329762180    177.2951100         0.9830
284     K00846.01   27.807562927    186.7135320 
15   K00847.01  80.872063900    203.8969600 4.73    0.7640
16    K00848.01 3.166464930 
17   K00849.01  10.355331770    170.9368500 3.09    0.9180
18 K00850.01    10.526294063    176.5225030 8.50
```

a single letter (K) from each line of the file.

So I tough to use `sed` or `echo` or the follow idea:

`cut -d \K -f file_in.dat > file_out.dat`

But  I found some problem with this idea.
Can someone help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try :

```
sed 's/K//' file_in.dat > file_out.dat
```

Comment: If there might be several `K`, better `sed 's/K//g' file_in.dat > file_out.dat`, or even `sed -i 's/K//g' file_in.dat` to edit in-place.

Answer (score 0):

There's no use in echo or cut, as they are mainly for printing the output and manipulation with columns. In your case you need `sed 's/K//g' file_in.dat > file_out.dat`, which replaces all occurences of K with nothing.

Comment: ...replaces the *first* occurrence of K with nothing.  Add the /g flag for *all* occurrences.

Comment: thanks for noticing, flag is needed here unless there is single occurence